# Is possible to keep secrets out of state?

Tags: terraform

For example could reference the password as an environment variable? Even if I did do that it would still be stored in state right?

```
# Configure the MySQL provider
provider "mysql" {
  endpoint = "my-database.example.com:3306"
  username = "app-user"
  password = "app-password"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

State snapshots include only the results of `resource`, `data`, and `output` blocks, so that Terraform can compare these with the configuration when creating a plan.

The arguments inside a `provider` block are not saved in state snapshots, because Terraform only needs the *current* arguments for the provider configuration, and never needs to compare with the previous.

Even though the provider arguments are not included in the state, it's best to keep specific credentials out of your configuration. Providers tend to offer arguments for credentials as a last resort for unusual situations, but should also offer other ways to provide credentials. For some providers there is some existing standard way to pass credentials, such as the AWS provider using the same credentials mechanisms as the AWS CLI. Other providers define their own mechanisms, such as environment variables.

For the MySQL provider in particular, we should set `endpoint` in the configuration because that describes *what Terraform is managing*, but we should use environment variables to specify *who is running Terraform*. We can use the `MYSQL_USERNAME` and `MYSQL_PASSWORD` environment variables to specify the credentials for the individual or system that is running Terraform.

---

A special exception to this is when Terraform itself is the one responsible for managing the credentials. In that case, the resource that provisioned the credentials will have its data (including the password) stored in the state. There is no way to avoid that because otherwise it would not be possible to use the password elsewhere in the configuration.

For Terraform configurations that *manage* credentials (rather than just *using* credentials), they should ideally be separated from other Terraform configurations and have their state snapshots stored in a location where they can be encrypted at rest and accessible only to the individuals or systems that will run Terraform against those configurations. In that case, treat the state snapshot itself as a secret.

Comment: this right. i guess for some reason i thought it was different because i was unfamiliar with the mysql provider- but I do this now will all my other providers (aws, datadog, etc) and i know its not keeping those creds in state!

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible. Your best option is using a safe and encrypted remote backend such as S3 + Dynamodb to keep your state files. I've also read about people using `git-crypt`, but never tried myself.

That said, you can keep secrets out of your source code using environment variables for inputs.